# Android : Activity stop timeout and ANR

Tags: android, timeout, android-anr-dialog

everyone. I got a worrisome ANR problem.

In the Log, My ActivityA starts ActivityB, and then ActivityA goes to onPause() and onStop() methods. After onStop() is completed for about 10s, ActivityManagerService prints this:

```html
Activity stop timeout for ActivityRecord{ActivityA}
Activity reported stop, but no longer stopping: ActivityRecord{ActivityA}
```

And then my ActivityA will be slicenced for a long time. If I input something during this time, an ANR dialog will show up.

I'm sure ActivityA has printed the message at the last Line of onStop() method every time. So the onStop() method should be completed already.

Why the ActivityManagerService still print these info? And why ActivityA has an ANR problem?

*The main thread in traces.txt ( I hope it will help ) :*

```html
"main" prio=5 tid=1 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x2cb39ca8 self=0x2cb26390
  | sysTid=3811 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[fopen-error:2] handle=721600852
  | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=74 stm=17 core=2
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x2cb39d78> (a java.lang.VMThread) held by tid=1 (main)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1205)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:325)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:813)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireQueued(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:846)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquire(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1175)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync.lock(ReentrantLock.java:180)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.lock(ReentrantLock.java:256)
  at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:555)
  at android.view.SurfaceView.onWindowVisibilityChanged(SurfaceView.java:234)
  at android.view.View.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(View.java:8004)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1077)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1077)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1077)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1077)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1077)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1237)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5030)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Post your onStop for ActivityA.  It looks like it never returns.

Comment: Sorry, I can't post detailed code for some reason. The onStop called several native methods (I know it may cause problem.). But the whole onStop finishes in about 15ms, which can be read from the log I added at the enter and exit of  this method. And I find that ActivityManagerService prints this after "Activity reported stop..." : "Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!"  (ActivityA is in a permanent app, it gets wakelock and releases it when screen off)

Comment: What is the solution?  I am facing a similar error...